# Doing the inverse of a calculation

Tags: google-sheets, gambling

For me to know how much I need to invest knowing how much I want in return, I do it this way:

Return expected → `D2`: `7.32`
Market odds → `C2`: `1.41`

Amount to invest → `E2`:

```
=(C2-1)*D2
```

Rounded result:

```
3.00
```

But what if I know how much I want to invest(`3.00`), how do I reverse this calculation?

Amount to invest → `E2`: `3.00`
Market odds → C2: `1.41`
Return expected→ `D2`: ???

Additional information for users to gambling tag:

I'm looking to invest in **Lay** on the Exchange market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `E2 = (C2-1)*D2`, then

- E2/D2 = (C2-1)
- D2/E2 = 1/(C2-1)
- D2 = E2/(C2-1)

So, according to your data:

- `Amount to invest` → E2: 3.00
- `Market odds` → C2: 1.41

You can compute `Return expected` as:

D2 = 3/(1.41-1) = ~7.317

Answer (score 2):

D2 is calculated like:

```
=E2/(C2-1)
```

[image]